Python: How to get SSRS Report Subscriptions published by different user via API
I'm using the SSRS API with Python 3 and need to get all reports and their subscriptions.
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#/info
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
import requests

req_url = r'http://<my_server_url>/reports/api/v2.0/Subscriptions'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNegotiateAuth()

report_response = session.get(req_url, stream=True)

report_response_json = report_response.json()

session.close()

# do stuff with json response, eventually export to CSV

This works for getting me all the information I need for reports that I created and published. However, there are reports published by other users on the server and I'd like to be able to get their report information too.

Are you a System Administrator on the Report Server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/grant-user-access-to-a-report-server?view=sql-server-ver16

No I don't think so; I was just given the server URL to publish reports to.

Seems like /CatalogItems returns everything, so the new workflow is to use that endpoint and then cycle through each item. Then make another get request using the ID of each item in the response.
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
import requests

api_url = r'http://<my_server>/reports/api/v2.0/'

# single-sign on
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNegotiateAuth()

# use Odata filtering to only get Reports and LinkedReports
# https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html#_Toc445374625
report_response = session.get(api_url + r"CatalogItems?%24filter=Type%20eq%20'Report'%20or%20Type%20eq%20'LinkedReport'")

report_response_json = report_response.json()
for report_item in report_response_json['value']:
    try:
        # documentation doesn't list the LinkedReport(Id)/Subscriptions endpoint, 
        # but it exists just like the Report(Id)/Subscriptions one
        # https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#/LinkedReports/GetLinkedReports
        subscription_request_response = session.get(api_url + report_item['Type'] + 's(' + report_item['Id'] + ')/Subscriptions')
        subscription_items = subscription_request_response.json()['value']

        if(len(subscription_items) == 0): # no subscriptions
            # do stuff
        else: # report has subscriptions
            for subscription_item in subscription_items:
                # do other stuff with each returned subscription dict
    except:
        # log error, do other stuff

session.close()

